# Power automate : How does mouse/keyboard automation work on minimized apps?

Tags: background, keyboard, mouse, power-automate, minimize

I'm willing to learn power automate because it seems to be a great tool with many features. Before I start, I want to know one thing or two if you can help me.

1. If I run a background flow which interacts with an app, will the app be minimized during the flow execution ? In that case, how would mouse instructions work ? I know it would be a virtual mouse but im wondering how I can tell it to click at a precise point on the screen since the app is minimized.
2. Some apps dont get refreshed with real time informations when minimized, you have to open them. Some are put to sleep. Is this a known issue on power automate background flow ?
3. Not a question here just to tell you I know could rather use specific tools but don't worry, I was just curious on that "mouse/keyboard" background thing.

I didn't actually try anything, but I am trying to visualise what could be done with power automate.